# Ansible module for managing DigitalOcean dashboard firewall

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean, firewall

I want to manage my **DigitalOcean firewall** via **Ansible**. But seems no such *module* is available in Ansible to manage *(add/remove firewall rule) firewall over the dashboard.*

Currently, we are using **UFW** on each machine but we want to disable them and want to use **DigtalOcean dashboard firewall**.

*Can you please guide me is it possible to manage DO dashboard firewall via Ansible or not?*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Among [DO modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#digital-ocean) there is only [digital_ocean_firewall_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/digital_ocean_firewall_facts_module.html#digital-ocean-firewall-facts-gather-facts-about-digitalocean-firewalls) to `"Gather facts about DigitalOcean firewalls"`. It is possible to use [doctl](https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl) `"A command line tool for DigitalOcean services"` to setup a DO firewall. See [How To Use Doctl, the Official DigitalOcean Command-Line Client](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-doctl-the-official-digitalocean-command-line-client).

See details [How To Secure Web Server Infrastructure With DigitalOcean Cloud Firewalls Using Doctl](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-web-server-infrastructure-with-digitalocean-cloud-firewalls-using-doctl) with examples on how to configure the DO firewall. For example as a hint

```
tasks:
- command: "doctl compute firewall create --name web-firewall
            --droplet-ids your_droplet_id
            --inbound-rules 'protocol:tcp,ports:22,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0'
            --outbound-rules 'protocol:icmp,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0 protocol:tcp,ports:all,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0 protocol:udp,ports:all,address:0.0'"
```

Comment: `doctl` throws an error if the firewall already exists, making this solution non-idempotent.

Comment: There's an existing PR to allow proper management of DO firewalls, though: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/46618